# How does eclipse workbench show JRE system library while viewing any java project in eclipse workbench?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I view eclipse java project in eclipse workbench theres this JRE system Library. Which file /folder contains that information in my Project as in If I create a project named 
'Test' in eclipse it will  contain the following files and folders

```
 -src
    -bin
    -.settings
    -.classpath
    -.project
```

Now does this entry

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/CDC-1.1%Foundation-1.1"/>
```

in my .classpath file correspond to the JRE system library that my eclipse workbench shows in my project?

Also could someone explain to me how Eclipse associates the libraries mentioned in .classpath to the java project?
Where do these libraries come in eclipse anyway?is there a plugin to manage libraries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath entry means that you have Execution Environment 'CDC-1.1 Foundation-1.1' set for the JRE for the project.

The mapping from Execution Environments to JREs is set in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments'

Comment: So basically the classpath entry that I have mentioned above is the reason why my workbench shows JRE System Library in my java project ?

Comment: Yes. A Java project will always show a JRE System Library if it is configured properly and will have a classpathentry like this.